# Duplicating rows in R matrix

Tags: r, sample, rep

I have a small matrix, say

```
x <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 5) # values 1:10 across 5 rows and 2 columns
```

The result is

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
```

What I want to be able to do now is duplicate random rows in x; for example, producing

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    5   10
[4,]    4    9 
[5,]    5   10
```

I believe the R function 'rep()' is the solution and also 'sample()', but I don't want to have to specify the size argument in sample(); i.e., I want an arbitrary number of rows to be duplicated each time.

Is there a simple way of accomplishing this using rep() and sample()?

Comment: @bouncyball Your implementation that you just deleted works. I would add it back for others having the same issue.

Comment: I was a bit confused on the size argument to sample(), thinking it had to be specified with something other than nrow(x)

Comment: If my implementation has solved your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [`sample`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) function. I've used `set.seed` for reproducibility, if you remove that line the results should change.

```
set.seed(1848) # reproducibility
x[sample(x = nrow(x), size = nrow(x), replace = T), ]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    5   10
[4,]    1    6
[5,]    5   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be as sample a `row number`  and replace that with another sampled `row number`. It will be as:

```
x[sample(1:nrow(x),1),] <- x[sample(1:nrow(x),1),]


x
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5   10
#[2,]    2    7
#[3,]    3    8
#[4,]    4    9
#[5,]    5   10
```

OR

Just to duplicate upto 3 random rows, solution could be:

```
x[sample(1:nrow(x),3),] <- x[sample(1:nrow(x),3),]
```